# Symfony 3/Doctrine - populate table with some rows while creating table schema

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I want to fill a database table as soon as it is created first time, may be with running the following command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --em=some_connection
```

Basically, this will be a static table with some static data. I need to do this in that way because the **database** will be created dynamically. So cannot populate that by hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

With datafixturesBundle .

It's really easy to implement just follow the tutorials and if you find problems just ask me .

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html